# Send multiple fields of data over socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, struct, udp, byte

I want to send packets over a socket which have the following format:

```
struct Packet{
   uint32_t  seqnum;
   uint16_t  check;
   char data[1024]
};
```

Each packet has a sequence number, a checksum, and the data that the packet contains. How could I put these 3 fields into a buffer to be sent over a socket, and then when received, the fields can be extracted? For example, is it possible to maybe make the first 4 bytes of the buffer the seqnum, the next 4 bytes the check, and then the remainder the data which is 1024 bytes? So the receiver will expect to receive a total of 1032 bytes and then should be able to extract the first 4 and make that seqnum, the next 4 and make that check sum and the last 1024 as the data? I am doing this over UDP so I cannot send the fields separately.

Comment: you can do that, but it is not optimal if your actual data may be much smaller than 1024. When your data is, say, 100 bytes or less, you would be wasting bandwidth.

Comment: Also, you would be increasing the chances that your packet will not reach the destination. It is not very common to have too large packets when using UDP. But, well, make it work first, and then later you will try to optimize it.

Comment: Don't use structs as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols.

Answer (score 0):

*edit - OP didn't ask for C++, however the underlying implementation is done in C if that helps.*

I modified a class from the Boost example website to suit your needs, it's a convenience wrapper for your buffers and struct.  This should suit your needs, but it doesn't take into account big or little endianess.

It makes it a lot easier when your message is always a fixed size, but adding another 4 byte integer to your header that holds message length will save you a lot of bandwidth and it's very simple to do.

```
message myMessage;

myMessage.setSequence(nextSequenceNumber);
myMessage.setCheckSum(mycheckSum);

 //assuming the message you have is a std::string
memcpy( myMessage.body(), message.c_str(), myMessage.body_length() );
myMessage.encode_header();
sendto(socket, myMessage.data(), myMessage.length(), 0, &my_sockaddrsizeof(my_sockaddr));

myMessage.reset();
recvfrom(socket, myMessage.data(), myMessage.length(), 0, &my_sockaddr, &my_sockaddr_len);

if(!myMessage.decodeHeader()){
// handle bad header/corrupt message
}

int32_t sequence = myMessage.getSequence();
int32_t checkSum = myMessage.getSheckSum();

class message
{
public:
    enum { check_length = 4 };
    enum { seq_length = 4 };
    enum { body_length = 1024 };
    message() : _checkSum(0), _sequence(0), _body_length(1024), _header_length(8) {}  // constructor + init list

    const char* data() const   { return data_; }
    char* data()               { return data_; }
    const char* body() const   { return data_ + check_length + seq_length; }
    char* body()               { return data_ + check_length + seq_length; }
    std::size_t length()   { return _body_length + _header_length; }
    std::size_t body_length() { return _body_length; }
    int32_t const& getCheckSum()  const { return _checkSum; }
    int32_t const& getSequence()  const { return _sequence; }
    void setCheckSum(const int32_t& s) { _checkSum = s; }
    void setSequence(const int32_t& s) { _sequence = s; }

    bool decode_header()
    {
        char check_sum[check_length + seq_length + 1] = "";
        char sequence[check_length + seq_length + 1] = "";
        strncat_s(check_sum, data_, seq_length);
        strncat_s(sequence, data_ + check_length, check_length);
        _checkSum = std::atoi(check_sum);
        _sequence = std::atoi(sequence);

        if (_checkSum == 0 || _sequence == 0)  
        {
            std::cout << "Header malfunction" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void encode_header()
    {
        char header[check_length + seq_length + 1] = "";
        std::memcpy(header, &_sequence, sizeof(int32_t));
        std::memcpy(header + seq_length, &_checkSum, sizeof(int32_t));
        std::memcpy(data_, header, check_length + seq_length);
    }

    void reset()
    {
        memset(&data_[0], 0, sizeof(data_));
        int32_t _checkSum = 0;
        int32_t _sequence = 0;
    }

private:
    char data_[check_length + seq_length + body_length];
    int32_t _body_length, _header_length;
    int32_t _checkSum;
    int32_t _sequence;
};
```

Comment: The question was tagged C, not C++.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure your struct is set up properly to have fields properly aligned at the proper byte boundaries.

So this is fine:

```
struct Packet{
   uint32_t seqnum;
   uint32_t check;
   char data[1024];
};
```

But this is not:

```
struct Packet{
   uint16_t other;
   // 2 bytes of padding exist here so seqnum sits on a 4-byte boundary
   uint32_t seqnum;
   uint32_t check;
   char data[1024];
};
```

Any integer fields larger than 8 bit should be converted to network byte order before sending and back to host byte order after receiving.  Use `htonl` and `ntohl` for 32-bit values and `htons` and `ntohs` for 16-bit values.

Once you've done that, you can send that structure directly:

```
struct Packet packet;
// populate packet
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
// perform error checking, call bind, etc.
int sendLen = sendto(socket, &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, &my_sockaddr, sizeof(my_sockaddr));
```

And similarly receive it:

```
struct Packet packet;
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
// perform error checking, call bind, etc.
int recvLen = recvfrom(socket, &packet, sizeof(packet), 0, &my_sockaddr, &my_sockaddr_len);
// read packet
```

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I mentioned byte ordering and the use of `htonl/s` and `ntohl/s`.  Though I admit I'm not aware of any architectures that align values of one size to offsets of a larger size.

Comment: You're using a language that gives you all the tools you need to write code that's guaranteed to work. Why make assumptions about alignment?